# Find with multiple conditions item in Table List Google Sheets

Tags: function, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a list with agents results + Rules of priority looking like this
[image]

**What should happen**:
In the Agents *Results list*, the formula should look for the line where all the rules are met.
And then return Agent name.
Like in the first rule (the  Hero's Name is hardcoded).

Agent 1 has Quality Result more than 99% **and** Productivity Result more than 115%. **So he is in the column Hero's Name.**

**My attempts to solve the task.**

1. To find agent's Name use INDEX function
2. To find **the row** argument for INDEX use MATCH function

**The obstacles I've met**

1. INDEX function returns only one result. What to do if several rows meet the Rule of Priority?
2. I can't use numeric range from/to in MATCH function to find row due to Rule of Priority that includes ranges (like Quality 99+ means all the values from 99.01% to 100%)
3. I can't use multiple conditions in MATCH to find the row that meets **both Quality and Productivity conditions** from Rules of priority

Please, help. I would be grateful for ideas on how this can be solved.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Your sheet is protected.  Please share it so anyone can EDIT it, as described in the link.  That is why you only share a sample/copy of your sheet, with non-sensitive data.  https://support.google.com/docs/thread/3808684?hl=en

Comment: @player0 Here it is 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11ugX2HJ-pW9eHnYaWlQqRFLavLzHLSB5viev1mFnENs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @kirkg13 thanks a lot! Corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=IFERROR(JOIN(", "; FiLTER(C5:C; A5:A >= 98%; 
                                 A5:A <  99%; 
                                 B5:B >= 110%; 
                                 B5:B <  115%)); "no one")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should use filter function:
To have all agents that meet conditions quality > 99 and productivity >115 % you can make a function:
c - agents
b - productivity
a - quality

```
=filter(c5:c,a5:a>0.99,b5:b>1.15)
```

this will produce you a column of agents.

For more conditions (ranges of productivity, quality), you just add more conditions into filter fuction: for productivity between 110 and 115 and quality between 98 and 99 you write:

```
=filter(c5:c,a5:a>0.98,a5:a<0.99,b5:b<1.15,b5:b>1.1)
```